# How does WordPress pass query information to paginated pages such as /page/2 and /page/3?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

How does WordPress make query information available to paginated pages?

For example, I have a WP_Query running on a custom page. It just outputs a list of posts, nothing wonderful. How does WP pass the query information to /page/2/ so that /page/2/ knows which posts to display?

Comment: $myquery = new wp_query($args) `print_r($myquery );` see all the information coming in it

Comment: That will just show me the query information?

Comment: nope also vars which hold other information like total number of result total no of pages  etc

Comment: if you have total 100 recs from a query and you have to show 10 records per page you can well guess  number of pages will be 10 and on second page records  from 11 to 20 will be displayed. all these information is in wp_query object and calculation is made on the basis of it

Comment: so how does the query information get made available to jobs/page/2, jobs/page/3 and so on? For example - how does WP know my 2nd results page is jobs/page/2? how does it share the query information which is originally available to page /jobs/. Why does jobs/page/2 display the 2nd page of results and not jobs/seasonal/page/2. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: there is a paged variable in wp_query object which keep tracks of your current page

Comment: i'm still not sure how the paged variable is relevant? I suppose I could rephrase my question: why does page 2 of results display on page jobs/page/2 and not job/blah/meh/page/2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for. Specifically the information on `WP->parse_request()`.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview

Answer (score 1):

WP_Query has some different properties which are used to decide which posts is displays, namely `offset`, `posts_per_page`, and in particular `paged`. Wordpress will parse your URL and find that you want page 2 and use that as the `paged` property for WP_Query.

Read more about [WP_Query pagination](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

Comment: ah right - it's the bit where WP parses the URL that i'd like to know more about. do you have any info on that?